# Javascripts geolocalization - User refuses to give data

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation

This JS function works correctly; but doesn't if the user refuse to give his localization by the browser.

How can I modify it?

```
function getPosition()
  {

  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showmyPosition);
    }
  else
    {
    alert("Geolocation doesn't work"); 
    }
  }

function showmyPosition(position)
  { 
 document.location.href="/near?lat="+  position.coords.latitude +"&lng="+ position.coords.longitude +"";
  }
```

Comment: If the user refuses to give their location, then you can't have it. Easy as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigation.geolocation` does not check if the user accepted geolocation, it only checks if the browser supports geolocation.

However, you can provide getCurrentPosition with an error callback, from which you can read the error. See the example below

```
function getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showmyPosition, errorCallback);
    }
    else {
       alert("Browser does not support geolocation");  
    }
}

function showmyPosition(position) {
    document.location.href = "/near?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lng=" + position.coords.longitude + "";
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    if (error.code === 1) {
        alert("User denied geolocation");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If user does not allow geolocation through browser, you can use the IP address to estimate their location.

You can sign up from API from http://ipinfodb.com